# SQL Server agent option in SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent, sql-server-express

I am using SQL Server 2008 Express. I don't have SQL Server Agent option in it. How can I enable it?

I have searched on internet, but couldn't find anything. Do I need to install anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, as found under the 'Management Tools' section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

If this is just for your development environment, you can pick up a copy of Developer Edition for about $50 US.  When you release, you will need a copy of Standard Edition or higher to be able to use the job agent.

Comment: Well, workgroup / web editions also support Agent (though web can only be used in certain scenarios). Also you'll want to make sure you don't use any Enterprise features in development (which Dev Edition will allow) that aren't supported on your deployment edition. Finally, make sure the dev edition and deployment edition *versions* match. I've seen lots of folks install 2008 R2 or 2012 locally and then try to deploy to 2008 in production...

Answer (score 0):

For development and otherwise, you can also create a batch file to fire it the job and then run the batch file via a windows scheduled task.